# Bind Winform datagridview to list of object with arrays

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, binding

There are many examples for bind a column to an external array (or list), but nothing for display a simple array inside a list of object.

In my code i have something like this:

```
public class ObjList {
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    public bool Param2 { get; set; }

...

    public string[] ArrParam { get; set; }
}
```

And there is a list of that object:

```
public List<ObjList> Params = new List<ObjList>();
```

Now, if I want see the list inside a datagridview, is simple:

```
dataGridParameters.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridParameters.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
dataGridParameters.DataSource = Params;
```

But it doesn't show the ArrParam column. So, I add a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to my datagriview.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ColComboBox.HeaderText = "ArrParam";
ColComboBox.Name = "ArrParam";
dataGridParameters.Columns.Add(ColComboBox);
```

With this code I can see a new column in datagridview, with header ArrParam, and all the cells are combobox, but the comboboxes are empty.

If I try to assign ColComboBox.DataSource, all the column's cell will be initialized with a list of data (but I don't want an unique list for all combobox!).

So I tried to force the datasource of every cell:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridParameters.Rows) {
   ObjList p = Params.Where(a => a.Param1 == (string)row.Cells["Param1"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
   if (p != null && p.ArrParam != null) {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = row.Cells["ArrParam"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
      if (cell != null) {
         cell.DataSource = p.ArrParam;
         cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
      }
   }
}
```

But combobox are still empty. I also tried:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridParameters.Rows) {
   ObjList p = Params.Where(a => a.Param1 == (string)row.Cells["Param1"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
   if (p != null && p.ArrParam != null) {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = row.Cells["ArrParam"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
      if (cell != null) {
         cell.Items.AddRange(p.ArrParam);
         cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
      }
   }
}
```

But nothing change, comboboxes are still empty.

UPDATE:
If I use a Dictionary<int, string> instead a string array, and assign cell datasource, seems work:

```
public class ObjList {
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    public bool Param2 { get; set; }

...
    public Dictionary<int, string> DictParam { get; set; }
    public string[] ArrParam { get; set; }
}
```

And before show the datagridview:

```
foreach (ObjList  p in Params) {
   if (p.ArrParam!= null){ 
      if (p.DictParam == null)
         p.DictParam = new Dictionary<int, string>();

      for (int i = 0; i <= p.ArrParam.Count(); i++) {
         p.DictParam .Add(i, p.ArrParam[i]);
      }
   }
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridParameters.Rows) {
   ObjList p = Params.Where(a => a.Param1 == (string)row.Cells["Param1"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
   if (p != null && p.ArrParam != null) {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = row.Cells["ArrParam"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
      if (cell != null) {
         cell.DataSource = p.DictParam;
         cell.ValueMember = "Value";
         cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
      }
   }
}
```

But not the first time! I need reload the whole parameters, reinit the datagridview and cells datasource, the second time the comboboxes are correctly initialized.

UPDATE:
Seems that is not possible bind DataGridViewComboBoxCell to a string array, we need a List of object or a dictionary, because the array can't give a ValueMember or a DisplayMember.

About the necessary reload, seems that the problem is initialize the datagridview content before assign datasource. If I show the DatagridView before datasource assignation, it works.
But really is needed show an empty datagridview before filling the data?

Comment: What is the business of the `ArrParam` in the `ObjList` model? Does it have a different set of string elements that you need to choose from? If yes, to set which property in that model? What you choose from and assign to are two different things.

Comment: Hi and thanks,
I only need to show and choose a different set of strings for each element in ObjList.
Load the specific datasource for each cell doesn't work like assign the datasource to the whole datagridview and the comboboxes are empty, and load the items inside the combobox give the same result. Seems it's a cell refresh problem, but there isn't a cell.Refresh() method, or a ColComboBox.Refresh() method.